# Is there a difference between computing LAB and RGB avg?

Tags: colors

I have a number of `RGB` pixel sets that I need to compute an average colour for. So far I have simply been averaging each `R`, `G` and `B` value separately to compute the average `RGB` value and then converting it into `LAB` for comparison against another colour with the DeltaE 2000 algorithm.

Is there any difference to the final computed `LAB` average if I instead first convert each individual `RGB` set to `LAB` and then average the `L`, `A` and `B` values separately?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, there's a difference. RGB values suffer from color metamerism which is where multiple combinations of R G and B can produce the same perceived color. My hunch is that averaging the RGB values will also get you a washed out version of the color as well.

Here's some rgb metamer examples:

light pink  233 200 244 vs 245 196 234

aqua         40 238 234 vs 99  235 224

light green  21 237  70 vs 78  234  62